# Почему после выполнения http запроса не работает программа?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, .net-core, httpclient

Пишу программу на WPF. Мне нужно сделать Get запрос по url и вытянуть оттуда информацию. Вот примерно следующий код:

```
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await _httpClient.GetAsync(ul); // <-- Error is here
responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string content = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

И вот мой `HttpClient`:

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
private readonly SocketsHttpHandler _socketHandler;

ctor()
{
   _socketHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler()
   {
      PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
      AllowAutoRedirect = true,
   };
   _httpClient = new HttpClient(_socketHandler, true);
}
```

Проблема в том, что при выполнении данного кода, точнее, указанной строки в коде, программа перестаёт работать. Ставил брейкпоинты на соответствующую строку и на следующую, но программа к следующей строке (`responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();`) не доходит, а просто перестаёт работать, так будто у меня вылетело исключение. `try/catch` ничего не ловят, сама форма НЕ ОТКРЫВАЕТСЯ.

Был совет поставить .ConfigureAwait(false) в конце данной строчки, поскольку это может быть deadlock, но тогда программа выдаёт неверные данные.

Интересно то, что до этого программа работала корректно, но в какой-то момент просто перестала работать.

С чем это может быть связанно и как это решить?

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил, я вынес вызов метода ещё в отдельный метод, поскольку я вызывал данный момент с http запросом в конструкторе формы